# zip error after 7-zip install and uninstall

Tags: windows, zip, cygwin, gnu

I am using zip in Cygwin under Windows 10 and after installing 7-Zip on my system and then uninstalling it, I get the following error when using zip on the command line in Cygwin when trying to zip any files:

```
    zip warning: name not matched: Files\7-zip
    zip warning: name not matched: testing
```

E.g. zipping 2 files a and b:

```
zip testing a b
```

will give the error. How do I get rid of this nuisance? 
Reinstalling zip did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a further extensive search with no answers I found out what the problem was.

7-Zip sets up an environment variable `ZIP=C:\Program Files\7-zip` and for some reason the existence of a ZIP variable interferes with the GNU zip utility.

I unset ZIP by doing `ctrl-Esc` and typing `env` which brought up the control panel option of "Edit environment variables for your account" and removed the ZIP variable and it now works.